# Get symfony route from controller action annotations

Tags: symfony

I have a controller action like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/delete/{id}", name="delete_post_modal")
 */
public function deleteAction(Post $post)
{
    // ...
}
```

The annotation `@Route` tells symfony to execute method `deleteAction` when route matches `delete_post_modal`. 
All of this works fine.

Question: Is there a way to reverse this functionality and get the route name from method name?

From the example above:

- I have: `PostController::deleteAction()` (or `self::deleteAction`)
- I need to get: `delete_post_modal`

thanks!

Comment: I am a laravel user which internally uses symfony and i think there is a class named Request that you can use to get the path info.

Comment: There is a console command that match route_name by url : router:match , hope that can help you. [link](http://johnkary.net/blog/useful-commands-for-efficient-symfony2-development/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

**update**

```
 $router = $this->container->get('router');

foreach ($router->getRouteCollection()->all() as $route => $params)
{
    $defaults = $params->getDefaults();

    if ( strpos($defaults['_controller'],'PostController::deleteAction') ) {
        $myroute = $route;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work to get the route of **current** request, but I need more generic method to generate route name by knowing controller and method name in general.